# Managed Metadata Column updates if List, but not Document

Tags: 2013, development, document-library, managed-metadata

I have a managed metadata column which is updated using the code below. If I pass in a List it updates. If I pass in a document, no error and no update.

(I tried using `SPItem` instead of `SPListItem`, from Googling)

```
string newval = "Charleston|ec12fde0-5e10-4308-9640-e0ab9e1b5c34,Charlotte|2f1cfc1f-538f-4728-a71e-a5a1c8558011,Columbia|38c5ca3e-a26e-4eae-a01e-60e2d0caa926";
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url))
{
   using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
       web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
       SPList olist = web.Lists[list];
       SPListItem iteml = olist.GetItemById(itemid);
        SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
        {
           var cityList = newval.Replace(",", ";");
           var newList = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomyFieldValueCollection(string.Empty);
           newList.PopulateFromLabelGuidPairs(cityList);
           iteml["Cities"] = newList ;
           iteml.Update();
        });
        web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have content types associated with the library?

Comment: SPItem is an abstract class. You wouldn't use this in the code you shared.

Comment: Do you mean that you're passing in a library? Passing a list isn't comparable to passing a single document.

Comment: The list is created from document with managed metadata columns added. The original add uploads the file, adds values to the MMD fields, all good.  Then I get the list item, modify the MMD values, and update. No error. for Item, updates correctly.  For document, returns no error, but no update.  I do not want to modify the document, just the MMD values

Comment: Yes, there is Content Type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved:

```
string newval = "Charleston|ec12fde0-5e10-4308-9640-e0ab9e1b5c34,Charlotte|2f1cfc1f-538f-4728-a71e-a5a1c8558011,Columbia|38c5ca3e-a26e-4eae-a01e-60e2d0caa926";
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url))
{
   using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
       web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
       SPList olist = web.Lists[list];
       SPListItem iteml = olist.GetItemById(itemid);
        SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
        {
           var cityList = newval.Replace(",", ";");
           var newList = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomyFieldValueCollection(string.Empty);
           newList.PopulateFromLabelGuidPairs(cityList);
           TaxonomyField taxCityField = (TaxonomyField)iteml.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName("Cities");
           taxCityField.SetFieldValue(iteml, newList);
           taxCityField.Update(); 
           iteml.Update();
        });
        web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
    }
}
```